# How to write web page for jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

Now I'm using jenkins to build the Android project. But there are many non-developers need download the latest apk file.

I just give them a account to login jenkins and enter the workspace to download the apk they want.

But now it need customization, it need a web page to let others can input some text and call jenkins to read it and change some commands by this input.

So my question is : Can I write another web page by html(or others) to cooperate with jenkins ? I don't know which keyword should I search in Google.

Comment: Can you clarify what text it is you need users to input, and how that should affect Jenkins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins has a [Remote access API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) that you can use to both read data such as getting artifacts from a build and make download links, and also to do things like trigger builds. The api is available both as Json and Xml.

If you are comfortable with html and javascript you can easily put together a page that can trigger builds, and get artifacts.

If you need "inputs" for your builds, you likely want to use [parametrized builds](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build)

You can, for example, use a HTTP POST to trigger a build with a parameter like so:

```
http://server/job/myjob/buildWithParameters?PARAMETER=Value
```

Comment: That's save my day! Thanks!